# Replace Space with "/" if adjacent word begins with same letter, else "&" Excel Macro VBA

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have been looking for a very long time for a macro that can loop through a column of cells and replace each space with `/` if the adjacent words begin with the same letter, else replace with `&`.

The number of 3 letter combinations in each cell can very from *blank* to an excess of 20+.

Example

```
DZP DOP DMM HTP HZW UTT
```

to

```
DZP/DOP/DMM&HTP/HZW&UTT
```

Each letter grouping that begins with D as DZP DOP should have their space replaced with `/` to become DZP/DOP but DMM and HTP should be DMM&HTP is the first letters of each word is different.

I know I need to compare length of string and relative position and then iterate the process with an If Then Else statements. But I am at a loss just to begin the if.

Furthermore I have found many sites on how to compare cells, but I have yet to find how to come words with in a cell.

Any help would be great, especially if you can explain how to write a comparative formula to compare very 4th character.

Thank you for you time.

Comment: do it in VBA. use the split function to break them into an array. Then iterate the array using if (left(arr[n],1) = left(arr[n+1],1) then add them to a string. if they match str+arr[n] +"/" arr[n+1]... etc You can use the mid function to look at the 4th char. or break it down and use te substring retuned and iterate until end of string using left(str,4)

Answer (score 3):

The below function will replace the spaces with slashes if the next word begins with the same letter. It will only work with words of exactly three letters.

```
Function ReplaceSpaces(StrIn As String) As String

'Start at the first space

If Len(StrIn) > 3 Then
    i = 4

    Do
        If Len(StrIn) > i And Mid(StrIn, i, 1) = " " Then
            If Mid(StrIn, i - 3, 1) = Mid(StrIn, i + 1, 1) Then
                StrIn = Left(StrIn, i - 1) & "/" & Right(StrIn, Len(StrIn) - i)
            Else
                StrIn = Left(StrIn, i - 1) & "&" & Right(StrIn, Len(StrIn) - i)
            End If
        End If
        Debug.Print Chr(34) & Mid(StrIn, i, 1) & Chr(34)
        i = i + 4
    Loop Until i > InStr(1, StrIn, " ")

    ReplaceSpaces = StrIn

End If

End Function
```

This second function will work with words of any length, including varied length (i.e. a 4-letter word followed by a 3-letter word, followed by a 6-letter word, etc.).

```
Function BetterReplaceSpaces(StrIn As String) As String
Dim lastfirstletter As Integer, i As Integer

lastfirstletter = 1
If InStr(1, StrIn, " ") > 0 Then
    i = InStr(1, StrIn, " ")
    Do
        'If Len(StrIn) > i And Mid(StrIn, i, 1) = " " Then
            If Mid(StrIn, lastfirstletter, 1) = Mid(StrIn, i + 1, 1) Then
                StrIn = Left(StrIn, i - 1) & "/" & Right(StrIn, Len(StrIn) - i)
            Else
                StrIn = Left(StrIn, i - 1) & "&" & Right(StrIn, Len(StrIn) - i)
            End If
        'End If
        Debug.Print Chr(34) & Mid(StrIn, i, 1) & Chr(34)
        lastfirstletter = i + 1
        i = InStr(1, StrIn, " ")
    Loop Until i = 0

    BetterReplaceSpaces = StrIn

End If


End Function
```

Comment: It works fantastic. I am very surprised to have gotten a response back so quickly but I am very appreciative. This will definitely help.